# Was the final transformation a blunder?

Tags: character, production-mistakes, miss-peregrines-home-for-peculiar

At the end of Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children, the main villain is disposed of, by his own petards. But during that scene, he seems to have transformed completely:

His eyes included. This was earlier explained by using contacts. But Barron shifted into the main character. How did he get contacts for his eyes? And he's shown to change his eyes back before the Hollow Gast takes them.

Was this just a blunder in filming?